# Handling Enum flags for a copy operation

Tags: c#, enum

I've just set up a bit of code to try and make things neater, but all I've really done, is add a whole bunch of nested `if` statements:

```
public void Copy(Copy copyType)
{    
    FrmProjectChooser frm = null;
    if (copyType.HasFlag(Copy.Single))
    {
        if (copyType.HasFlag(Copy.Estimations) && copyType.HasFlag(Copy.SubItems))
        {
            // Single item, with sub items and estimations
            List<WB> items = new List<WB> { (WB)treeWBS.GetDataRecordByNode(treeWBS.FocusedNode) };
            items.AddRange(_WBSManager.GetAllChildren(items[0].idWBS));
            List<CTREstimation> estimations = new List<CTREstimation>();
            foreach (WB wbs in items)
                estimations.AddRange(CTREstimationsManager.Instance.GetEstimationsForWBS(wbs.idWBS));
            frm = new FrmProjectChooser(items, estimations);
        }
        else if (copyType.HasFlag(Copy.Estimations))
        {
            // Single item, with estimations.
            WB wbsItem = treeWBS.GetDataRecordByNode(treeWBS.FocusedNode) as WB;
            if (wbsItem != null)
                frm = new FrmProjectChooser(new List<WB> { wbsItem },
                    CTREstimationsManager.Instance.GetEstimationsForWBS(wbsItem.idWBS));
        }
        else if (copyType.HasFlag(Copy.SubItems))
        {
            // Single item, with sub items
            List<WB> items = new List<WB> { (WB)treeWBS.GetDataRecordByNode(treeWBS.FocusedNode) };
            items.AddRange(_WBSManager.GetAllChildren(items[0].idWBS));
            frm = new FrmProjectChooser(items);
        }
        else
        {
            // Single item
            WB wbsItem = treeWBS.GetDataRecordByNode(treeWBS.FocusedNode) as WB;
            if (wbsItem != null)
                frm = new FrmProjectChooser(new List<WB> {wbsItem});
        }
    }
    else if (copyType.HasFlag(Copy.All))
    {
        if (copyType.HasFlag(Copy.Estimations))
        {
            // All items, with estimations.
            List<WB> wbsItems = _WBSManager.GetWBSForProject(CurrentProject.idProjects);
            List<CTREstimation> estimations = new List<CTREstimation>();
            foreach (WB wbs in wbsItems)
                estimations.AddRange(CTREstimationsManager.Instance.GetEstimationsForWBS(wbs.idWBS));
            frm = new FrmProjectChooser(wbsItems, estimations);
        }
        else
        {
            // All items
            frm = new FrmProjectChooser(_WBSManager.GetWBSForProject(CurrentProject.idProjects));
        }
    }

    if (frm != null)
        frm.ShowDialog();
}

[Flags]
private enum Copy
{
    None = 0,
    Single = 1, // Straight copy of single item
    SubItems = 1 << 1, // Include any children in the copy
    Estimations = 1 << 2, // Include estimations in the copy
    All = 1 << 3 // Copy all items
}
```

The code will pull "Items" from a `TreeList`. "Sub Items" are of the same type as "Items", but `Estimations` are a different type. I don't think it's very neat. I've tried googling similar titles to this question but I can't really find anything that helps.

Is there anything I can do to make this neater?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6040/52915)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is based on what @Matt said. I thought the idea was very good and it could be pushed a step further.

Using @Matt's idea, your code wouldn't contain nested `ifs`, but you still chain `ifs`. Of course you could use a `switch`, but you still have the same problem. Lots of code in the same method, and we don't like crowded methods.

The solution? (Well.. *my* solution)

A dictionary!

Now, I don't know what your doing inside your ifs, which is sad, because I can't help you much further. But it would look like this :

```
//Right now, I assume your method is in an object, so I put the dictionary static, and it will be populated in the static ctor of the object.
private static readonly Dictionary<Copy,Action> _mapCopy = new Dictionary<Copy,Action>();

static YourObjectWhatever()
{
    _mapCopy.Add(Copy.All  | Copy.Estimations, CopyAllEstimations);
    _mapCopy.Add(Copy.Single | Copy.Estimations, CopySingleEstimations);
    //etc...
}

private static void CopyAllEstimations()
{
    //Do stuff..
}

private static void CopySingleEstimations()
{
    //Do stuff..
}

public void Copy(Copy copyType)
{
    Action action = null;
    if(!_mapCopy.TryGetValue(copyType, out action))
        throw new ArgumentException("The copy type doesn't have an associated action");

    action();
}
```

Now, your logic is separated in multiple methods, which is better but **not** perfect. If you want to push this even farther (for testability for example), you'd need to implement an `interface`, let's say `ICopyAction` (I can't tell more because there's a little lack of context). So now we'd have :

```
public interface ICopyAction
{
    void Copy(/*I'm guessing you'd have parameters*/);
}

public class CopyAllEstimations : ICopyAction
{
    public void Copy()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
//etc...
```

And the usage :

```
//Same assumption
private static readonly Dictionary<Copy,ICopyAction> _mapCopy = new Dictionary<Copy,ICopyAction>();

static YourObjectWhatever()
{
    _mapCopy.Add(Copy.All  | Copy.Estimations, new CopyAllEstimations());
    //etc...
}

public void Copy(Copy copyType)
{
    ICopyAction action = null;
    if(!_mapCopy.TryGetValue(copyType, out action))
        throw new ArgumentException("The copy type doesn't have an associated action");

    action.Copy();
}
```

This method works as well if you want to have parameters to your method, but I didn't this explanation because I don't know if you need it..

Answer (score 7):

For an aesthetic point of view, you could define some constants:

```
AllEstimations = Copy.All | Copy.Estimations
SingleEstimations = Copy.Single | Copy.Estimations
etc.
```

You could then check the value against these constants and create a single level if statement:

```
if (copyType == SingleEstimationsSubItems)
{}
elseif (copyType == SingleEstimations)
{}
elseif (....
```

I'm not claiming this will improve performance, but it will make the code more readable.